# Homotopy between idempotents of small difference

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. It is known that if $p$ and $q$ are projections in $A$ with

$$\|p-q\|<1,$$

then $p$ and $q$ are homotopic through a path of projections.

**Question:** Does a similar statement hold for idempotents? More precisely, if $e$ and $f$ are idempotents in $A$, does there exist $\delta>0$ such that $e$ and $f$ are homotopic through idempotents whenever
$$\|e-f\|<\delta?$$

Comment: For what it's worth, this is certainly true for operator algebras over finite dimensional space. In this context, two idempotents are homotopic iff they have the same trace, and this trace must be an integer (equal to the rank). Thus, if $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, we have $\|e - f\| < 1$ implies that
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}(e) - \operatorname{Tr}(f)| \leq |\operatorname{Tr}(e - f)| \leq \|e - f\| < 1
$$
so that $e,f$ are indeed homotopic.

Comment: Yes.  Prove that $u=ef+(1-e)(1-f)$ is close to 1, hence invertible, and that $eu=uf$, so $e=ufu^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lemma (11.2.7) in (*Rørdam, M.; Larsen, F.; Laustsen, N.*, An introduction to (K)-theory for (C^*)-algebras, London Mathematical Society Student Texts. 49. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xii, 242 p. (2000). [ZBL0967.19001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0967.19001).), for every idempotent $e$ in $A$, one has that
$$
  \rho (e):= ee^*(1 + (e - e^*)(e^*-e))^{-1}
  $$
is a projection (self-adjoint idempotent) and $e\sim_h\rho (e)$ (meaning that $e$ and $\rho (e)$ are  homotopic through a path
of idempotents).

Thus, given $e$ and $f$ satisfying $\Vert e-f\Vert <\delta $ (the precise value of $\delta $ to be filled in later), we have that
$e\sim_h\rho (e)$ and   $f\sim_h\rho (f)$, so if we can manage to prove that   $\rho (e)\sim_h\rho (f)$, we will get, by transitivity,
that $e\sim_h f$.
As noted in the OP, since $\rho (e)$ and $\rho (f)$ are projections, it would be enough to  prove that $\Vert \rho (e)-\rho (f)\Vert <1$.

It is not difficult to see that the range of an idempotent element $e$ coincides with the range of $\rho (e)$, so $\rho (e)$ is in fact the
orthogonal projection onto the range of $e$.

Given idempotents $e$ and $f$, let us henceforth write $E$ and $F$ for the ranges of $e$ and $f$, respectively, and by
$p$ and $q$ the orthogonal projections onto $E$ and $F$, which amounts to saying that $p=\rho (e)$ and $q=\rho (f)$.

Define
$$
  \alpha (E, F) = \sup\{\text{dist}(x,F): x\in E,\  \Vert x\Vert \leq 1\},
  $$
$$
  \beta (E, F) = \sup\{\text{dist}(x,E): x\in F,\  \Vert x\Vert \leq 1\}.
  $$
and finally put
$$
  d(E, F) = \max\{\alpha (E, F),\beta (E, F)\}.
  $$

**Lemma 1**. We have
$$
  d(E,F)\leq \Vert e-f\Vert .
  $$
If moreover  $e$ and $f$ are self-adjoint, then
$$
  \Vert e-f\Vert \leq 2d(E,F).
  $$

*Proof*.  For $x$ in $E$ with $\Vert x\Vert \leq 1$, we have
$$
  \text{dist}(x,F) \leq  \Vert x-f(x)\Vert  = \Vert e(x)-f(x)\Vert  \leq  \Vert e-f\Vert ,
  $$
so $\alpha (E, F)\leq \Vert e-f\Vert $, and it can be likewise proved that    $\beta (E, F)\leq \Vert e-f\Vert $, whence  $d(E, F)\leq \Vert e-f\Vert $.

Now assume that $e$ and $f$ are self-adjoint, so in particular  $\Vert e\Vert  \leq 1$ and  $\Vert f\Vert  \leq 1$.
For every $x$ in $H$ with $\Vert x\Vert \leq 1$, we have that   $e(x)\in E$ and $\Vert e(x)\Vert \leq 1$.  Moreover, the element in $F$ closest to $e(x)$
is $f(e(x))$, so
$$
  \Vert e(x)-f(e(x))\Vert  =  \text{dist}(e(x), F) \leq  \alpha (E,F)\leq d(E,F).
  $$
Taking the supremum for all $x$ in $H$ with $\Vert x\Vert \leq 1$, we  deduce that
$$
  \Vert e-fe\Vert \leq d(E,F),
  $$
and a symmetric  reasoning gives
$\Vert f-ef\Vert \leq d(E,F)$, so also
$$
  \Vert f-fe\Vert  =   \Vert (f-ef)^*\Vert  =   \Vert f-ef\Vert \leq d(E,F).
  $$
This said we obtain
$$
  \Vert e-f\Vert  =
  \Vert e-fe+fe-f\Vert  \leq
  \Vert e-fe\Vert +\Vert fe-f\Vert  \leq
  2d(E,F). 
  \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
  $$

**Lemma 2**.  We have
$$
  \Vert p-q\Vert \leq 2\Vert e-f\Vert .
  $$

*Proof*.  This follows from
$$
  \Vert p-q\Vert \leq 2d(E,F)\leq 2\Vert e-f\Vert .
  \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
  $$

**Theorem**.  If $\Vert e-f\Vert <1/2$, then $e\sim_hf$.

*Proof*.  By Lemma (2) we have
$$
  \Vert \rho(e)-\rho(f)\Vert =\Vert p-q\Vert \leq 2\Vert e-f\Vert <1,
  $$
so the conclusion follows as indicated above. $\qquad \blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that
$$
\Vert f-e\Vert < {1\over \Vert e \Vert +\Vert f \Vert},  \tag{*}
$$
let $u=ef+(1-e)(1-f)$.  Then
$$
  \Vert u-1\Vert =
  \Vert ef-e-f+ef\Vert=
  \Vert e(f-e) - (f-e)f \Vert \leq $$ $$ \leq
  \Vert e \Vert\Vert f-e\Vert + \Vert f-e \Vert\Vert f \Vert =
  (\Vert e \Vert +\Vert f \Vert)(\Vert f-e\Vert) <1.
  $$
This implies that $u$ is invertible.  Moreover we have that
$eu=uf$, whence $e=ufu^{-1}$.

Notice that the fact that $\Vert u-1\Vert <1$ implies not only that $u$ is invertible, but also that the power series defining the logarithm converges at $u$, so that $u=e^h$, for some $h$ in $A$. We then obtain a path of idempotents joining $f$ and $e$ by
$$u_t=e^{th}fe^{-th}.$$

---

**Remarks**:

1. This does not provide a universal $\delta$, as required in the OP, but at least shows that being homotopically equivalent is invariant under small perturbations.
2. My impression is that there is no universal $\delta$ and I'll report back should I be able to prove it.
3. An elementary estimate shows that if $\Vert f-e\Vert <(4\Vert e\Vert )^{-1}$, then condition (*) above holds, so we deduce that $e$ is
   homotopically equivalent to every idempotent element in a neighborhood of $e$.

Comment: I am thankful for the upvote but this answer is now superseeded by the one below, so I think I should delete it :-(

Comment: It's still a nice answer I think! This method would have worked to give $\delta=1$ if $e$ and $f$ were projections. Your answer illustrates the subtle difference in the case of idempotents.

Comment: An idempotent has norm either $0$ or $\geq 1$, so $\frac{1}{\|e\|+\|f\|}\leq\frac12$, so you get the same constant.

Comment: @Aweygan, Your inequality is correct but it implies that $$\Vert e - f\Vert < {1 \over \Vert e \Vert + \Vert f \Vert} \Rightarrow \Vert e-f \Vert < {1 \over 2}$$ and not vice versa.