# Homotopy between invertibles of small difference

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This question is in some sense dual to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836958/homotopy-between-idempotents-of-small-difference).

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. It is known that if $u$ and $v$ are unitaries in $A$ with

$$\|u-v\|<2,$$

then $u$ and $v$ are homotopic through a path of unitaries.

**Question:** Does a similar statement hold for invertible elements? More precisely, if $a$ and $b$ are invertible in $A$, does there exist $\delta>0$ such that $a$ and $b$ are homotopic through invertible elements whenever
$$\|a-b\|<\delta?$$
(In particular, what if $b$ is the identity?)

Comment: If $b=1$, $\delta=1$.

Comment: It is difficult to think of pair of invertible elements in a $C^*$ algebra that fail to be homotopic

Comment: @BenGrossmann Invertibles in the Calkin algebra which arise from Fredholm operators with different indices

Comment: @Aweygan Nice thanks for the example

Comment: @Aweygan I think there's an issue with your example: a Fredholm operator with non-zero index cannot be invertible even though it corresponds to an invertible element of the Calkin algebra.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's not what I'm saying.  If $S$ and $T$ are Fredholm operators with different indices, then their images in the Calkin algebra will be invertibles (in the Calkin algebra) which are not homotopic.

Comment: @Aweygan Of course.... thanks for clarifying

Comment: Complementing @Awey, if $\|u-v\|<\|u^{-1}\|^{-1}$ then ($v$ is invertible even if it was not already assumed and) $u$ and $v$ are homotopic.

Comment: Contrary to the idempotent case, there is no universal constant here because you can always take two non-homotopic unitaries $u$ and $v$ and consider $u'=\varepsilon u$ and $v'=\varepsilon v$, for $\varepsilon$ small.  Then $\|u'-v'\|<3\varepsilon$ but $u'$ and $v'$ are not homotopic.